# how to use the following curl cmd in java?

Tags: java, curl, post, https, request

I have the following https script request and I need to convert it into a java code. I'm not really familiar with java and I'm struggling a bit. the request has a basic authentication and a proxy. could anyone help with this?

```
***************    Shell script    ************************** 
#!/bin/sh 

UPLOAD_URL=https://your-server-name/bbb/ddd/upload 

PROXY=http://proxyservername:8080 

CONFIGID=test_upload 
DATAFILE=testfile.csv 
CACERT=SBC-cacert.pem  

USER=username PASS=passWord678 

curl --cacert $CACERT -u ${USER}:${PASS} -F "datafile=@${DATAFILE}" -F  "configId=${CONFIGID}" -x "$PROXY" "$UPLOAD_URL"
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't going to be complete, but it's too long for a simple comment.

This is a big question and as phrased, probably too large for a stack overflow question. You're going to have to use an HTTP implementation. There are some to choose from. Java comes with HttpUrlConnection, but I personally really don't like it. Here's an article on it:

[Do a Simple HTTP Request in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request)

There are also a variety of existing stack overflow questions of How to do an HTTP connection in Java. I'm not going to list them. You can do a proper search.

I personally have used Apache HTTPComponents. The main page:

[Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

This is going to take you some time. When you get stuck, you can ask more pointed questions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In the end I managed to use curl in a script. it was the fastest and most straight forward way to proceed.